# Convert Byte Array to Text With Byte Order Mark Detection

Tags: .net, string, utf8-decode

Trying to figure out the byte[] equivalent of this

```
    string getText = string.Empty;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader((System.IO.Stream)File.OpenRead(unc), true))
    {
        getText = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Would like to convert a byte[] to string with specified byte order mark detection option like is available with StreamReader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `StreamReader` - just wrap the byte array in a `MemoryStream`. (It's not clear why you're casting `File.OpenRead` to `Stream`, by the way...)

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(data)))
```

Comment: I think you are suggesting I take the cast off.   Took the cast off, it works, so I will leave it off.  Thanks